# PHP + SockJS + Redis: Unicast

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, redis

***My application stack:***

On my server runs a **Redis** server. The **PHP** backend communicates with **Predis** library with the **Redis** server. It will publish messages. These messages will be fetched by my **Redis** client (**node.js**) and pushed to the connected websocket clients (with **SockJS**).

***My problem:***

It runs well. At least for broadcast messages. Now I came to the point I need to send a unicast message and I'm stuck... How to connect the user on the backend side (sender of messages) with the connected client of the websocket?

**Code snippets:**

***PHP***

```
$redis = new Client();
$redis->publish('updates', Random::getUniqueString());
```

***Redis client on node.js server***

```
redis.subscribe('updates');

redis.on('message', function(channel, data) {
    for (var id in sockets) {
        if (sockets.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            sockets[id].write(data);
        }
    }
});
```

***SockJS client***

```
mySocketFactory.setHandler('message', function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

Like I said. Working well but the `id` used for the socket connection is not known by the PHP backend.

Edit: One idea I got in mind is to use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem. When the socket connection is established I sent a request to my PHP backend and ask for the user id. This is stored on the node.js server. When messages are incoming there is a check if they are for specific user and handle them only for them.

So, what do I store exactly on my node server?

```
var sockets = {}; // {connection_id: socket_connection}

var connIdToUser = {}; // {connection_id: user_id}

var connIdsForUser = {}; // {user_id: [connection_id_1, connection_id_2 ,...]}


socketServer.on('connection', function(conn) {
    sockets[conn.id] = conn;

    var options = {
        host: os.hostname(),
        port: 80,
        path: '/user/id',
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            var userId = JSON.parse(chunk).id;
            connIdToUser[conn.id] = userId;

            if (!connIdsForUser.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
                connIdsForUser[userId] = [];
            }
            connIdsForUser[userId].push(conn.id);

            console.log('connection id ' + conn.id + ' related to user id ' + userId);
        });
    });
    req.end();

    conn.on('close', function() {
        console.log('connection lost ' + conn.id);

        // remove connection id from stack for user
        var connections = connIdsForUser[connIdToUser[conn.id]];
        var index = connections.indexOf(conn.id);
        if (index > -1) {
            connections.splice(index, 1);
        }

        // remove connection at all
        delete sockets[conn.id];
        // remove relation between connection id and user
        delete connIdToUser[conn.id];
    });
});
```

The reason for storing the relation between user id an connection id twice is the different use case I need either for sending a message or deleting the connection for the close event. Otherwise I would have to use a nested loop.
As you can see deleting a socket is fairly easy. Although deleting the connection from the connection stack of an user is a little bit complicated.

Let's continue with the sending of a message. Here I defined a structure of the message I get from the Redis server:

```
{
  targets: [], // array of unit ids (can be empty)
  data: <mixed> // the real data
}
```

Sending the data to the sockets looks like:

```
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    // unicast/multicast
    if (message.targets.length > 0) {
        message.targets.forEach(function(userId) {
            if (connIdsForUser[userId] !== undefined) {
                connIdsForUser[userId].forEach(function(connId) {
                    sockets[connId].write(message.data);
                });
            }
        });
    // broadcast
    } else {
        for (var id in sockets) {
            if (sockets.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                sockets[id].write(message.data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Since I store the connection stack per user it is quite easy to send the data to all sockets related to a specific user. So what I can do now is unicast (array with one user id), multicast (array with more than one user id) and broadcast (empty array).

It's working well for my use case.